# Make vector with 2 elements with equal chance in R

Tags: r

I want to create an R vector with two repeat elements. A length of the array is 200.

But each element can be either 'x' or 'y'.

an element can be x or y with equal chance.

Is there any grammatical function in R to do above task?

Please someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way to do it is to use `rbinom`. Step by step, generate first a vecotr of 0 and 1, then change it into x and y:

```
vec = ifelse(rbinom(200, 1, 0.5)==0,"x","y"))
```

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized.  You don't need the `sapply` loop

Answer (score 0):

We need a little bit more information to be helpful, but if you want a vector of 200 values, 100 x's and 100 y's, then just do this:

```
t <- rep(c('X','Y'), 100)
```

If you want this in a random order:

```
t <- sample(t)
```

Comment: It's not necessarily true that you expect to see the exactly 100 X's and Y's under the described simulation scenario. Perhaps `t <- sample(c('X','Y'), 200, replace=T)` would be a reasonable interpretation of the desired result as well. Each element would be X or Y with the same chance, but the total number of X's and Y's may be different

Comment: I guess I did not understand the questions. I didn't realize the goal was simulation, not just creation of a vector.

Comment: Perhaps I've misinterpreted. It's not entirely clear form the question; but chances are one of these two suggestions should work.